# vSync for gameplay in monitor and VR headset in Unity not being consistent?

Tags: unity, unityscript, frame-rate, htc-vive

Following my [previous question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/159273/the-value-of-vsync-on-vsync-count-in-unity), I'm building a project, my monitor refresh rate is 60Hz, and in my project I have set my [vSync value](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/QualitySettings-vSyncCount.html) into 2 so I can get 30fps.

```
QualitySettings.vSyncCount = 2
```

It worked perfectly, I built my project and I got stable 30fps. But after I plugged my VR headset (HTC Vive) to play the same project, my framerate drops and only reach around 10fps. Why is this happening ? FYI, Vive's refresh rate is 90Hz. In this case, will vSync adjust itself to my monitor or Vive's refresh rate ?